# distortion using gvr android sdk 1.190.0

Tags: gvr-android-sdk

I am using the gvr-android-sdk-1.190.0 video360 sample. If I play a stereo video like the example video, I have a distortion.
If I load the video in a built in player app that comes with the vr headset (pico g2 4k) it shows correct, with no distortion.
I have a screenshot attached where you can see the distortion on the white lines and also on the green square.
Is it possible to say why is that and how to fix it?

*edit*
I have to note, that the problem also occurs if I use a monoscopic video. But then the distortion does not appear that much.

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2VlGQWH9PioGhSdCjsP4c-O58OuLCWh/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out by myself:

The following is written in MediaLoader.java:

```
/** The 360 x 180 sphere has 15 degree quads. Increase these if lines in your video look wavy. */
  private static final int DEFAULT_SPHERE_ROWS = 12;
  private static final int DEFAULT_SPHERE_COLUMNS = 24;
```

Increasing the values for rows/columns solved the problem